# #UWP Change all fontcolor of richeditbox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I made a code that change fontcolor of selection in richeditbox.

```
RightRange.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = FontColorPicker.Color;
```

But how can i change all color of document?

Comment: Have you tried to set the `Background` property of the `RichEditBox`?

Comment: I can change background property, but I want to change fontcolor at once.

Comment: What do you mean with all color of document? Have you selected the whole text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know how to change `ForegroundColor` of the selection in [`RichEditBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RichEditBox), for change the `ForgroundColor` of all the document, you could just select all than change the color. Set the [selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextselection) range from 0 to the `EndPosition` will select all.

```
richEditBox.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
richEditBox.Document.Selection.SetRange(0, richEditBox.Document.Selection.EndPosition);
richEditBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
```